# Fullscreen hover popup behavior in OpenGL window and Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I am developing a Windows 11 application using C++, OpenGL and Win32. I've been using a trick that apps such as Visual Studio Code, Discord, Steam and others use, namely to draw the entire window using a graphics API like DirectX, OpenGL or Vulkan (in my case OpenGL). One of the main tricks is to remove the caption bar area which effectively makes the entire window a client area. Thus, the "caption bar" can be drawn using OpenGL which eliminates the problems with using `WM_NCPAINT`.

The way I've gone about implementing this is to handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` where the caption bar area can be eliminated, then it's just a matter of creating an OpenGL context and drawing to the window. The problem however is that the popup window (listed below) that is shown in native Windows apps when the user hovers over the "maximize" button is not appearing when `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is handled.

[image: Example of native fullscreen hover popup]

Also, I am handling `WM_NCHITTEST` correctly by returning `HTMAXBUTTON` when the cursor is in the desired location and then maximizing the window. This of course works, but the native popup is not shown. You might say, "Well, what did you expect by drawing the entire window in OpenGL?", well in that case, how come that other apps using the same techniques like Visual Studio Code has this very popup when the user hovers of the maximize button?

I've done extensive research through tools like Microsoft Spy++ and found out that apps like Visual Studio Code do indeed draw the entire window using the DirectX graphics API. Below I've attached an image of the current behaviour of my application when hovering the custom maximize button:

[image: Current hovering behaviour]

As you can see above, no fullscren popup is appearing when hovering. `WM_NCHITTEST` is handled properly since `HTMAXBUTTON` is returned when the cursor is in this location, which is confirmed by the fact that clicking in this location indeed maximizes the application. Here's the code used for handling `WM_NCCALCSIZE`:

```cpp
if (message == WM_NCCALCSIZE) {
    if (wParam == TRUE) {
        // ------ Hack to remove the title bar (non-client) area ------
        // In order to hide the standard title bar we must change
        // the NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS, which dictates the title bar area.
        //
        // In Windows 10 we can set the top component to '0', which
        // in effect hides the default title bar.
        // However, for unknown reasons this does not work in
        // Windows 11, instead we are required to set the top
        // component to '1' in order to get the same effect.
        //
        // Thus, we must first check the Windows version before
        // altering the NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS structure.

        Win32Utilities& instance = Win32Utilities::Instance();
        int top = instance.getWindowsVersionString() == "Windows 11" ? 1 : 0;

        LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS ncParams = (LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS) lParam;
        ncParams->rgrc[0].top += top;
        ncParams->rgrc[0].left += 0;
        ncParams->rgrc[0].bottom -= 0;
        ncParams->rgrc[0].right -= 0;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can ignore the tricks used in this message, since it will effectively set the top component to 1 if it's Windows 11 and 0 otherwise. If I remove this piece of code the standard title bar will be visible again, see the image below:

[image: Using no WM_NCCALCSIZE handling]

The interesting thing here is that the window popup is indeed properly drawn over the OpenGL context, but this only works when hovering the native maximize button. Bear in mind that `WM_NCHITTEST` is still handled manually. Thus, it seems like returning `HTMAXBUTTON` is not the only requirement for displaying this popup. The ultimate question is then: How do I make this maximize hover popup appear in a Win32/OpenGL application?

Edit 1:
After some more digging it seems that the problem (as suggested by @
user7860670) has to do with the handling of the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message. More specifically, the message is currently only handled when `wParam` is `TRUE`. Furthermore, as requested, here's the current hit test function:

```cpp
LRESULT WindowWin32::HitTestNCA(HWND hWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
  {
    // Get the point coordinates for the hit test
    POINT ptMouse = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };

    // Get the window rectangle.
    RECT rcWindow;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rcWindow);

    // Determine if the hit test is for resizing. Default middle (1,1)
    USHORT uRow = 1;
    USHORT uCol = 1;
    bool fOnResizeBorder = false;

    // Determine if the point is at the top or bottom of the window
    if (ptMouse.y >= rcWindow.top && ptMouse.y < rcWindow.top + 29)
    {
      fOnResizeBorder = (ptMouse.y <= rcWindow.top + 8);
      uRow = 0;
    }
    else if (ptMouse.y < rcWindow.bottom && ptMouse.y >= rcWindow.bottom - 10)
    {
      uRow = 2;
    }

    // Determine if the point is on the left or right side of the window
    if (ptMouse.x >= rcWindow.left && ptMouse.x < rcWindow.left + 10)
    {
      uCol = 0; // left side
    }
    else if (ptMouse.x < rcWindow.right && ptMouse.x >= rcWindow.right - 10)
    {
      uCol = 2; // right side
    }

    // Maximize button
    if (uRow == 0 && ptMouse.x >= rcWindow.right - 60 && ptMouse.x < rcWindow.right - 30) {
      return HTMAXBUTTON;
    }

    if (ptMouse.x >= rcWindow.left && ptMouse.x < rcWindow.right &&
        ptMouse.y >= rcWindow.top && ptMouse.y < rcWindow.bottom &&
        uRow == 1 && uCol == 1) {
          return HTCLIENT;
    }

    // Hit test (HTTOPLEFT, ... HTBOTTOMRIGHT)
    LRESULT hitTests[3][3] = 
    {
      { HTTOPLEFT,    fOnResizeBorder ? HTTOP : HTCAPTION,    HTTOPRIGHT },
      { HTLEFT,       HTNOWHERE,     HTRIGHT },
      { HTBOTTOMLEFT, HTBOTTOM, HTBOTTOMRIGHT },
    };

    return hitTests[uRow][uCol];
}
```

**Edit 2**: Since the question is now blocked from being answered and others discussed irrelevancies such as Windows version strings; I managed to solve the problem on my own. The problem was `WM_NCCALCSIZE` all along. Here's the implementation of it that works:

```cpp
if (message == WM_NCCALCSIZE) {
    // ------ Hack to remove the title bar (non-client) area ------
    // In order to hide the standard title bar we must change
    // the NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS, which dictates the title bar area.
    //
    // In Windows 10 we can set the top component to '0', which
    // in effect hides the default title bar.
    // However, for unknown reasons this does not work in
    // Windows 11, instead we are required to set the top
    // component to '1' in order to get the same effect.
    //
    // Thus, we must first check the Windows version before
    // altering inflation of the window.

    Win32Utilities& instance = Win32Utilities::Instance();
    const int d = instance.getWindowsVersionString() == "Windows 11" ? 1 : 0;
    InflateRect((LPRECT)lParam, -d, -d);
}
```

Comment: `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is not handled if `wParam`  is not `TRUE`. No `WM_NCHITTEST` code is present in the question.

Comment: @user7860670 Does `WM_NCCALCSIZE` need to be handled if it's `FALSE`? The documentation states that: "If `wParam` is `FALSE`, the application does not need to indicate the valid part of the client area."

Comment: The documentation states "If the wParam parameter is FALSE, the application should return zero."

Comment: Ever wondered why Microsoft jumped straight from Windows 8 to Windows 10, and never released Windows 9? `instance.getWindowsVersionString() == "Windows 11"` - That's why (or rather, the `osName.startsWith("windows 9")` dilemma). If you can arrange to use a data type that holds more structure than a character string, then do.

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah, yeah I know. It's not like the code is going to be released anytime soon or is optimal in any sense... Either way, this seems irrelevant to the question I asked

Comment: @IInspectable that reasoning was a bit nonsense, because the place where someone wrote `startsWith("Windows 9")` was the same place where they would've had to add more hardcoded strings for Windows versions - they could have fixed both at the same time

Comment: @user253751 The `startsWith("Windows 9")` logic was generally used to distinguish between the Win9x line of products and the WinNT line of products. It wasn't used to determine a particular version, but a product.

Comment: @IInspectable the code was like `if(winver == blah) str="Windows 95"; else if(winver==blah) str="Windows 98"; else if(winver==blah) str="Windows XP"; ........ if(str.startsWith("Windows 9"))`

Comment: @user253751 Not sure what you're getting at here. Clearly, programs that had this specific check didn't call a version API and constructed a version string. They went straight for the registry. Just because it's wrong doesn't mean that you won't see it in the wild.

Comment: @IInspectable except the one with this specific check that is always cited (i.e. Java) did call a version API and construct a version string

Comment: @user253751 I didn't cite a specific example, so I don't know how accurate *"always"* is here. Though I've patched *multiple* games in the past that used just this to determine whether they were running on Windows NT. And if so, they would exit. Because, you know, Windows NT would not ever support DirectX.